# Active record query linked with select box

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using an active record query to group values by type and average them. Each grouped type has a distinct average. I'm currently able to display all of the distinct averages. I plan to use javascript in conjunction with a select box to display only one average at a time. How should I set up my select box so that when a user selects a type from the drop down, it only displays the corresponding average from the query?

An example: There are 5 groups (Group A, B, C, D and E). Each group has multiple members that each get two scores. The average scores for each group as a whole are A: 65 & 40, B: 72 & 80, C: 73 & 65, D: 84 & 21, and E: 91 & 31. I'd like a user to be able to select a group from a dropdown and have the app only display the corresponding averages.

In the model:

```
def average_groupscore
     scores.select("AVG(scoreone) as avg_score, AVG(scoretwo) as avg_scoretwo, groupa").group("groups")
end
```

In the view:

```
<% @groupscore.each do |item| %>
     <div id="groupscore1"><%= item.avg_score.round %></div>
     <div id="groupscore2"><%= item.avg_scoretwo.round %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML data attributes.

```
<% @groupscore.each do |item| %>
     <div data-groupscore=1><%= item.avg_score.round %></div>
     <div data-groupscore=2><%= item.avg_scoretwo.round %></div>
<% end %>
```

Javascript w/ JQuery:

```
$('groupSelect').on('change', function() {
  $('[data-groupscore]').each( function(index, element) {
    element.style.display = 'none'
  })
  group = $('#groupSelect')[0].value //Get the value of your select box
  $('[data-groupscore='+group+']').each( function(index, element) {
    element.style.display = 'block'
  })
})
```

(Not the best Javascript, but gets the job done - hide everything, then show the selected things)

Or you can go heavier-duty and start playing around with AJAX and HTML replacement, client side MVC, etc.